# My hamster was left in his ball all day. Will he be okay?

Tags: health, injury, hamsters

My hamster was left in his ball by my nephew which I wasn’t watching at the time but he was the only one in my room when I went to the bathroom. I didn’t hear anything throughout the day (the ball rolling) so I figured he was asleep. My poor baby was found at 1:40 am and he was making a loud noise in the bathroom because his ball was stuck between baskets. I picked him up immediately and saw a dot of blood and the ball was foggy and there was a bunch of poop in the ball. I immediately put him back in his cage so he can eat and drink water and he did but will he die?

Comment: Go to a vet if you are worried about the health of your pet. Do not wait for guesses of strangers of the internet! We can not examine your hamster like a vet could do. Even calling a vet and ask for first aid you could do would help your hamster more than waiting.

Answer (score 2):

**Blood is not a good sign. A veterinary check is necessary.**

Normally, hamsters do not suffer physiological damage from getting stuck in a ball, provided that there are no stairs he can fall from. **Just remember that psychological damage is as important as physiological damage, so do not leave your hamsters unattended in his/her ball for a long time.**

Poo and urine is expected. Both of them might be the natural need of the animal to relieve itself. Alternatively, both of them might be due to the extra stress the animal endured. Regardless, poo and urine do not require a vet visit on their own.

Blood is probably due to one of the limbs of the hamster getting stuck in one of the slits in the ball. Most balls have some precautions to prevent limb injury, but even these precautions are not 100% effective. An alternative source of blood might be the ball hitting at a wall quite fast and hamster getting his lips or mouth cut by his teeth due to the impact.

**Regardless of the cause of bleeding, consult a vet whenever you see blood.**